# How to check if my machine has 3rd party remote access software installed?

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

How do I find if someone who is not authorized can access my desktop remotely?

I know when someone knows my password, he can remotely access my machine using my user, password from RDP, How do I stop someone access my machine remotely?
In Windows 10 Pro machine I can disable RDP remote access but how do I disable someone from accessing Windows 10 Home edition machine?

How do I check if someone has installed any 3rd party application in my system ( in both windows 10 pro and Home )  to remotely connect to PC?

Comment: Windows by default, does not allow remote desktop client access, unless you specifically enable it.  You simply check which programs you have installed, to verify, you don't have remote desktop software installed.  The only way by default, anyone could have access, is if you installed third-party software to allow it.

Comment: @Ramhound assume a person gets access to user & password of our systems administrator in the office im working...can that person access our workstations remotely using RDP administrator?

Comment: It depends. And that's not a question we can answer here. There are too many variables and factors involved. Concerns about your work computer environment should be taken up with your technical staff and management.

Answer (score 1):

Even with user-name/password, nobody can access your computers from the
exterior, as this would require:

- The router to pass RDP connections through its firewall.
- The router to do port-forwarding of the connections to the computers
  under attack. This requires using a different port specific to each computer.
- The computers to have enabled RDP access in Windows and in their firewalls
- The computers to have added the named user account to the
  Remote Desktop Users group in Windows.

If even one such condition is absent, RDP is not possible.
Or in other words, allowing RDP requires non-trivial work
by an administrator of each Windows computer and a
network administrator. It's not enabled by default.